# How to synchronize and redistribute data WITHOUT interpolation?

Tags: python, pandas, synchronization, interpolation, reindex

Suppose I have a DataFrame like this, which is supposed to measure energy consumtpions every 15 minutes for a whole House and, separately, also for the Oven of that house.
Unfortunately, once I put them together I can see that the measurements are not synchronized:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame()

df['timestamp1'] = ['27/06/2021  11:50:00', '27/06/2021  12:05:00', '27/06/2021  12:20:00', '27/06/2021  12:35:00', '27/06/2021  12:55:00', '27/06/2021  13:05:00' ]
df['Energy House'] = [814,642,473,783,386,503]

df['timestamp2'] = ['27/06/2021  12:00:00', '27/06/2021  12:15:00', '27/06/2021  12:35:00', '27/06/2021  12:45:00', '27/06/2021  13:00:00', '27/06/2021  13:15:00']
df['Energy Oven'] = [160,40,175,337,50,19]

             timestamp1  Energy House            timestamp2  Energy Oven
0  27/06/2021  11:50:00           814  27/06/2021  12:00:00          160
1  27/06/2021  12:05:00           642  27/06/2021  12:15:00           40
2  27/06/2021  12:20:00           473  27/06/2021  12:35:00          175
3  27/06/2021  12:35:00           783  27/06/2021  12:45:00          337
4  27/06/2021  12:55:00           386  27/06/2021  13:00:00           50
5  27/06/2021  13:05:00           503  27/06/2021  13:15:00           19
```

What I want to achieve, overall, is to **synchronize** the energy consumption of the Oven with respect to the consumption of the whole House.

Note the problem here is double: on one side the Oven's data are 10 minutes ahead with respect to the House's data (this is the basic part of the question), but addiotionally the data **don't always respect the 15 minutes rule** (see row number 2, where Oven measures 20 minutes consumption, and the same happens at row 4 for House's consumtpions). Therefore there's no uniformity in timestamps for both of the columns.

***Alternative 1***: we synchronize data by making sure that **Oven's measurements adapt to the timing of the House's measurements**, also changing the Oven's energy consumtpions according to the timings change, even if the House is not respecting the 15 minutes rule.

***Alternative 2***: first we re-distribute only the House's data evenly over 15 minutes sharp, then we do the same procedure separately for the Oven... So the final result will still be a perfect synchronization, but all of the original timings will be lost.

If possible, it would be important for me to do this re-distribution of the energy data **WITHOUT interpolation** . My idea is that, since we are talking about energy (and not power) consumed along 15 minutes, interpolation is not necessary. For example the data of the Oven can be re-distributed in this way (example for the row number 0, just a concept):

- "Oven_new (@ 12:05)" = last 10 minutes of "Oven_old (@12:00)" + first 5 minutes of "Oven_old (@12:15)"

Which mathematically means to **multiply by** some simple **time fractions**, written in minutes:

- "Oven_new (@ 12:05)" = 160*((60-50)/15) + 40*((05-00)/15)

Can you help me to find a solution both for Alternative 1 and Alternative 2, without the use of interpolation? Do you think that my idea about re-distribution is correct or is it better to interpolate with the function "reindex"?

Comment: @Corralien for the formulas that I've seen I think that the concept of interpolation is a bit different, but it's possible that I'm wrong. If you know how to code it with an interpolation (maybe using reindex) I can compare your results with mine :)

Comment: `"Oven_new (@ 12:05)" = last 10 minutes of "Oven_old (@12:00)" + first 5 minutes of "Oven_old (@12:15)"` sounds like the very normal interpolation to me.